# PHP: echo xml data

Tags: php, xml, http-post, echo, httpresponse

I have HTTP(S) response data in xml format as displayed below, on making HTTP(S) post to a REST endpoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GetTransactionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.xxxxxxxxxxx">
  <Errors xmlns:a="http://schemas.xxxxxxxxxx" />
  <TransactionStatusCode>Completed</TransactionStatusCode>
    <Transaction xmlns:a="http://schemas.xxxxxxxxx">
      <a:AmountPaid>10.00</a:AmountPaid>
      <a:StartDate>2008-08-25</a:StartDate>
      <a:MerchantDefinedData>Testing</a:MerchantDefinedData>
    </Transaction>
  </GetTransactionResponse>
```

Now, I want to echo some of the above columns as like:

> TransactionStatusCode: Completed
>  AmountPaid: 10.00
>  StartDate:
>   2008-08-25

Comment: your xml provided is invalid. `<a:StartDate>2008-08-25</a:StartDateTime>` opening and closing tags mismatch

Comment: Hi Nouphal.M, i have updated the mistyped code. Have u got any idea to solve this???